# Get the same specific date on each month of the whole year

Tags: php, date, time

I am working on a "cut-off" date and I need to set it on every month. Say, I set the cut-off date to August 25 for this year, then it should be September 25, October 25 and so on till the year ends.

Here's the code I have:

```
$now = "2015-08-25"; 
$nextDate = getCutoffDate($now);
echo $nextDate; 

function getCutoffDate($start_date) 
{    
  $date_array = explode("-",$start_date); // split the array
  // var_dump($date_array);
  $year = $date_array[0];
  $month = $date_array[1];
  $day = $date_array[2];

  /*if (date('n', $now)==12)
  {
    return date("Y-m-d",strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $start_date) . "+1 month"));
  }*/

  if (date("d") <= $day) {
    $billMonth =  date_format(date_create(), 'm');
  }
  else{
    $billMonth = date_format(date_modify(date_create(), 'first day of next month'), 'm');
  }
  // echo date("d").' '. $billMonth.'<br>';
  $billMonthDays = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, ($billMonth), date("Y"));
  // echo $billMonthDays.'<br>';
  if ($billMonthDays > $day) {
    $billDay = $day;
  } else {
    $billDay = $billMonthDays;
  }
}
```

I got this from here: http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/php-calculating-monthly

It returns the same date for the next month only, but how do I get the specific date of EACH month of the current year? Kindly leave your thoughts. Still a newbie here, sorry.

Comment: Watch out for "strange" dates: 29-30-31 are not present in every month!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, this should be enough:

```
<?php

for($i=8; $i<=12; $i++) {
    echo sprintf('25-%02d-2015', $i) . '<br>';
}
```

but if you need more flexible way:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('25-08-2015');

function getCutoffDate($date) {
    $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $date->format('n'), $date->format('Y'));
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P' . $days .'D'));
    return $date;
}

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $date = getCutoffDate($date);
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y') . '<br>';
}
```

This should print:

```
25-09-2015
25-10-2015
25-11-2015
25-12-2015
25-01-2016
```

Comment: 29-11-2020<br>29-12-2020<br>29-01-2021<br>01-03-2021<br>01-04-2021<br> as you see after feb dates changed from 29 to 01. how can we skip a month if particular date doesn't exist in that month ?

Comment: @PraffulPanwar `if ($date->format('d') == '29') { echo....` maybe ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64424925/monthly-recurring-event-on-specific-date-and-skip-any-month-if-have-less-no-of-d