# Monthly recurring event on specific date and skip any month if have less no of days compare to user's selected date

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I am creating a app where user can create monthly event (Just like Google/Outlook), so if user has selected `31st date of any month` and next month have `30 days` than all next dates are changing to `30th`.

Same goes with `30th`, lets say user selected `30th of December` than after Feb all next date is changing to `28th`.

so if in next month days are lesser than user's selected date its changing the date to that.

**Example :**
Start Date : `2020-10-31`
End Date : `2021-11-30`

```
$diffInMonths = $startDate->diffInMonths($endDate);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $diffInMonths; $i++) {
    $newStartDate = $i == 0 ? $startDate : $startDate->addMonthWithNoOverflow();
    print('<pre>' . print_r($newStartDate->toDateString(), true) . '</pre>');
}
```

its giving output like this

```
2020-10-31
2020-11-30
2020-12-30
2021-01-30
2021-02-28
2021-03-28
2021-04-28
2021-05-28
2021-06-28
2021-07-28
2021-08-28
2021-09-28
2021-10-28
```

What i need is skip the month if in that month have less days than user;s selected date. With Above example the correct output should be

```
2020-10-31 //November has less than 31st day
2020-12-31
2021-01-31 //Feb has less than 31st day
2021-03-31 //April has less than 31st day
2021-05-31 //June & July has less than 31st day
2021-07-31 
2021-08-31 //September has less than 31st day
2021-10-31
```

Struggling on this from last 2-3 days so any Kind of help or guidance will made my day :)

Comment: Is there a function `addMonthWithOverflow()`?

Comment: The method is from Carbon.

Answer (score 1):

This might be dumb way of doing this, but as i am running out of time so here is solution

```
$dateRange = Carbon::parse($callPlanner->start_date)->toPeriod($callPlanner->end_date, 1, 'month');
        $startDate = Carbon::parse($callPlanner->start_date);

        foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
            // compare the event date with end of month date
            if ($startDate->day <= $date->endOfMonth()->day) {
                //create new date with this month's year, month and event start date
                $newDate = Carbon::createFromDate($date->endOfMonth()->year, $date->endOfMonth()->month, $startDate->day);
                echo $newDate->toDateString(). "\n";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`addMonths()` add a month to a date. with no overflow, it makes the end of the next month, which is suppose `2020-02-29`. in the next step it adds another month to `2020-02-29` and that makes the next date `2020-03-29` because it just added a month. you don't call it to update the date. so your solution would be using `lastOfMonth()`

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse('2020-01-31');
$endDate = Carbon::parse('2020-12-31');
$diffInMonths = $startDate->diffInMonths($endDate);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $diffInMonths; $i++) {
    $newStartDate = $i == 0 ? $startDate : $startDate->addMonthWithNoOverflow()->lastOfMonth();
    print('<pre>' . print_r($newStartDate->toDateString(), true) . '</pre>');
}
```

which will give you dates like

```
2020-01-31
2020-02-29
2020-03-31
2020-04-30
2020-05-31
2020-06-30
2020-07-31
2020-08-31
2020-09-30
2020-10-31
2020-11-30
2020-12-31
```

with addMonth you can't skip months that has less days. you have to check it manually with some condition. like

```
$startDate = Carbon::parse('2020-10-31');
$endDate = Carbon::parse('2021-11-30');
$highestDate = $startDate->format('d');
$diffInMonths = $startDate->diffInMonths($endDate);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $diffInMonths; $i++) {
    $newStartDate = $i == 0 ? $startDate : $startDate->addMonthWithNoOverflow()->lastOfMonth();
    if ($newStartDate->format('d') >= $highestDate) {
        print('<pre>' . print_r($newStartDate->toDateString(), true) . '</pre>');
    } 
}
```

the output is

```
2020-10-31
2020-12-31
2021-01-31
2021-03-31
2021-05-31
2021-07-31
2021-08-31
2021-10-31
```

Comment: Change the date from 31st to 30th and output will be <pre>2020-10-30</pre>
<pre>2020-11-30</pre>
<pre>2021-04-30</pre>
<pre>2021-06-30</pre>
<pre>2021-09-30</pre>
<pre>2021-11-30</pre> this is also wrong as 30th is there in all the month except feb

Comment: update your code to for comparison condition from === to >= output is <pre>2020-10-30</pre>
<pre>2020-11-30</pre>
<pre>2020-12-31</pre>
<pre>2021-01-31</pre>
<pre>2021-03-31</pre>
<pre>2021-04-30</pre>
<pre>2021-05-31</pre>
<pre>2021-06-30</pre>
<pre>2021-07-31</pre>
<pre>2021-08-31</pre>
<pre>2021-09-30</pre>
<pre>2021-10-31</pre>
<pre>2021-11-30</pre> i already workaround with lastOfMonth but i actually don't need lastofmonth in any case that we can only use for comparison

Comment: well if its ok to take equal or greater than date, just update the comparison condition and you will get your desired output. you are asking if anyone selects any date like 1, 2, 5, 15, 20, or 27, what will be the output??

Comment: even if i change the condition to  >= it will wrong no as you can see in 2 comment of this thread. well the desired output is if date is equal or below 28 it will give me all month as no month are shorter than 28 days. if its more than 28 than it should skip Feb if its there in the start and end date range. if the date is 31 it will skip all those month having lesser than 31 days

Answer (score 0):

In such cases (similar to monthly subscriptions issues), it could be better to always start from the first date instead of chaining the additions:

```
$diffInMonths = $startDate->diffInMonths($endDate);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $diffInMonths; $i++) {
    $newStartDate = $startDate->copy()->addMonthsWithNoOverflow($i + 1);
    print('<pre>' . print_r($newStartDate->toDateString(), true) . '</pre>');
}
```

This way, you get last day of month is the day is not available but it does not change next iterations.

Note that `->copy()` is not needed if you use `CarbonImmutable`.